# Detect a change in a variable and respond accordingly [Lua]

Tags: variables, lua

I want to check a variable and see if it changes. I know it's probably doable with loops but I don't want to use those. The way I want the check to respond is that once the variable changes, I can choose which function to use accordingly.

Comment: Not possible. A programming language would be really slow if it had to detect event hooks for every variable change. You could write a function that you can call in any situation where the variable might change. Without more details about your problem, there's not much more I can tell you.

Comment: You can use a table and meta methods to do what your looking for if a table is allowed

Answer (score 2):

If you **really** want this to be transparent and don't care too much about speed and possibly breaking things, you could just use metatables:

```lua
local name = "proxied" -- The name of your variable
do local proxy
   setmetatable(_G, {
      __index=function(self,idx) if idx==name then return proxy end end;
      __newindex=function(self,idx,val) if idx==name then proxy=val; getmetatable(self).callback(val) else rawset(self,idx,val) end end;
      callback=function(val) print("Proxied variable set to "..tostring(val)) end;
   })
end
```

Please note that this is

- Slow
- Ugly
- Brittle
- Just a bad idea in general

Answer (score 0):

Honnestly the only way to do it as far as I know is by using loops. You could do something like this though:

```lua
var = "Hello, World!"
changed_var = var

function onChangedVar()
     --Whatever you want to happen when the variable changes
end

while true do
     if var ~= unchanged_var then
          onChangedVar()
          break
     end
end
```